# inspection of code shows code that should not be there or be there as it is

Tags: windows, apache, dhtml

I'm working with an application written in dHTML and running on a Windows 10 laptop using the Apache server.  I have some lines of simple code that generate a 2 SELECT statements as follows.

```
print "   Choose an effort: <SELECT NAME='echoice' CLASS='slcts' SIZE='16' STYLE='width:180px' ONMOUSEOVER=\"setStatus2('Only efforts with measures your authorized to work with are shown.');\" ONMOUSEOUT=\"setStatus2(' ');\" ONCHANGE=\"Loadem('choice');\">\n";

foreach $iline (@ilines) {
  print "<OPTION VALUE='$iline'>$iline</OPTION>\n";
}

print "</SELECT>\n";

print "Choose $what: <SELECT NAME='choice' CLASS='slcts' SIZE='16' STYLE='width:180px'>\n";

if ($cmfunction eq 'MeasureDescriptions' && $action eq 'U') {         
  print "<OPTION SELECTED VALUE='new'>new</OPTION>\n";
  $imo = 1;
}

 foreach $mline (@mlines) {
   $thestr = ($i == 0 && !$imo) ? 'SELECTED' : '' ; # Select 1st measure if not a single model.                
   print "<OPTION $thestr VALUE='$mline'>$mline</OPTION>\n";        
   $i++;
 }

 print "</SELECT>\n";
```

I don't seem to be able to change the contents of this field as long as the first select is there.  First I put a new unique character in the 2nd SELECT text each test to tell me if I'm executing the module version I think I am.  I always see the unique character.

I have tried the following.

1. comment out the inner 2 print statements,
2. change >new< to >new1<,
3. assign 'dog' to the 0 position of the mlines array, and
4. add a print after the Option loop to add a 'dog' option.

In all four cases, the choice SELECT had the same options as it had before any of the tests (1-4) were implemented.  But if I remove the first select,
I can then modify the options of the 2nd select.  The debugger image of the above code follows with both selects.

```
Choose an effort: <SELECT NAME='echoice' CLASS='slcts' SIZE='16' STYLE='width:180px' ONMOUSEOVER="setStatus2('Only efforts with measures your authorized to work with are shown.');" ONMOUSEOUT="setStatus2(' ');" ONCHANGE="Loadem('choice');">
<OPTION SELECTED VALUE='all'>all</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE='Health'>Health</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE='HealthCare'>HealthCare</OPTION>
</SELECT>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Choose a measure !: <SELECT NAME='choice' multiple CLASS='slcts' SIZE='16' STYLE='width:180px' ONMOUSEOVER="setStatus2('Only measures your authorized to work with are shown.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Select a measure for a formal definition.');" ONMOUSEOUT="setStatus2(' ');" ONCLICK='doFRef(event,this,this.form)'>
<OPTION SELECTED VALUE='new'>new</OPTION>
<OPTION  VALUE='HEComp90'>HEComp90</OPTION>
<OPTION  VALUE='HECompAtBirth'>HECompAtBirth</OPTION>
<OPTION  VALUE='healthy'>healthy</OPTION>
<OPTION  VALUE='infant'>infant</OPTION>
<OPTION  VALUE='maternal'>maternal</OPTION>
<OPTION  VALUE='stillbirths'>stillbirths</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

The debugger code with only one select follows.  I changed new to new1 and added the line and line2 options.  But if I put the first select back in,
I can't modify the 2nd select and it contains what is shown in the 1st debugger image.

```
<OPTION SELECTED VALUE='new'>new1</OPTION>
<OPTION  VALUE='line'>line</OPTION>
<OPTION  VALUE='HEComp90'>HEComp90</OPTION>
<OPTION  VALUE='HECompAtBirth'>HECompAtBirth</OPTION>
<OPTION  VALUE='healthy'>healthy</OPTION>
<OPTION  VALUE='infant'>infant</OPTION>
<OPTION  VALUE='maternal'>maternal</OPTION>
<OPTION  VALUE='stillbirths'>stillbirths</OPTION>
<OPTION  VALUE='line2'>line2</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

I don't understand this.  Any help will be appreciated.  It must be me.

Thanks,
craigt

Answer (score 0):

It was me.   There is an ONLOAD process that executed another process that preps
the content of that field that was not written correctly.  I've corrected that process and all works as expected now.  This question is closed.   And I apologize for my oversight and thank everyone that took a look.